# Sass-lint is no longer maintained-- now what?

Tags: open-source, software-development, web-development, lint

[Sass-lint](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint#this-project-is-currently-unmaintained---last-developmentstable-release-october-2017) had its documentation updated in September 2019 to state that the project was no longer being maintained.  While it may have a stable release, if there will be no new bugfixes or improvements this feels like a step towards the project's deprecation.

Sass-lint is a great development tool in the front end web development space for anyone using [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/).  I'm interested if there are any popular alternatives that might be a likely successor to Sass-lint.

The features of Sass-lint that are critical for my purposes are:

- Supports `sass` and `scss` syntax
- Has a CLI that can integrate with CI workflows
- Has an easy JSON configuration syntax, and the tool will look upward through parent directories to find configs
- The config allows for nuanced enabling, disabling, or tweaking of rules, in a manner similar to other popular linters like [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) and [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/)
- Also like other popular linters, has a syntax for enabling, disabling or tweaking of rules directly in source code using [specially formed comments](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint#disabling-linters-via-source)
- Wide editor integration-- Sublime Text is the most important for myself, but as I frequently work on teams where several editors are being used by different devs, it is important that we can all use a shared config to drive a linter that can be run on all our different editors.
- Cross-OS compatibility-- similar to the above, for my *own* purposes I need it to run on MacOS & Ubuntu, but because I frequently collaborate with Windows users it would be good if they could leverage the same tool chain.
- *Free* (or with a free tier)-- it would be difficult for me to make a case for adoption of a tool that drives a large cost per developer.  That said, if the cost of an alternative was relatively low it might be feasible.

Up until now Sass-lint had generally met my needs, but if it is no longer being maintained I am concerned that bugs will not be getting resolved and new features will languish.  For instance, ESLint has a `--fix` flag that it can be run with that will automatically fix certain issues-- Sass-lint lacks such a feature.  There are a few issues open requesting the feature.  There are [226 open issues in all](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+fix) on the project which now have no chance of being resolved or answered.

So, if I were to call out the ways in which Sass-lint is failing to meet my needs that I would require in an alternative:

- Is still under active development/maintenance
- Is popular or growing-- ideally on the way to becoming a well-established project that will increase its chance of wide adoption
- *Ideally* it would leverage the same rule name and configurations as Sass-lint, or possibly alias the Sass-lint rules for easier adoption
- Built/runs in NodeJS is *nice* but not a requirement

The front end web dev ecosystem is kind of strange-- ideally one moves with the trend and doesn't end up stuck on some "also-ran" tool that never saw wide adoption.  Looking around I don't see anyone making note that this popular package is no longer supported, and I am wondering if I am behind the trend or ahead of it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

18+ months later and I think that [Stylelint](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/about) is probably the best path forward for those looking for a logical successor to [Sass-linst](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint#this-project-is-currently-unmaintained---last-developmentstable-release-october-2017).

Looking at my original list of requirements:

- Supports `sass` and `scss` syntax 
   **It supports these and more**
- Has a CLI that can integrate with CI workflows 
   **[It has a CLI](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/usage/cli)**
- Has an easy JSON configuration syntax, and the tool will look upward through parent directories to find configs 
   **[Configurable via a `.stylelintrc`](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure)**
- The config allows for nuanced enabling, disabling, or tweaking of rules, in a manner similar to other popular linters like [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) and [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) 
   **yep**
- Also like other popular linters, has a syntax for enabling, disabling or tweaking of rules directly in source code using [specially formed comments](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint#disabling-linters-via-source) 
   **[Nuanced disabling via comments is supported](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/ignore-code)**
- Wide editor integration-- Sublime Text is the most important for myself, but as I frequently work on teams where several editors are being used by different devs, it is important that we can all use a shared config to drive a linter that can be run on all our different editors. 
   **[Several editor integrations are available](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/integrations/editor)**
- Cross-OS compatibility-- similar to the above, for my *own* purposes I need it to run on MacOS & Ubuntu, but because I frequently collaborate with Windows users it would be good if they could leverage the same tool chain. 
   **NodeJS-based, so it should run everywhere Node can**
- *Free* (or with a free tier)-- it would be difficult for me to make a case for adoption of a tool that drives a large cost per developer.  That said, if the cost of an alternative was relatively low it might be feasible. 
   **Free and Open Source**

It appears to still be well-maintained and getting regular releases-- I anticipate I will be moving forward switching some personal projects over to Stylelint very soon.